# JAXB 2.1 - Customize xs:any binding

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I want to generate java code from xsd using JAXB 2.1 XJC. I have an xsd schema provided and I can't change it. I would like to use **xjc:simple** mode while generating java classes from xml schema.

In the xsd there are elements:

```
<xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
```

As it is stated here: http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_of__xs_any___.html I expected that these elements will be binded to:

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
public Object any;
```

but when I use simple binding mode **xjc:simple** I have:

```
@XmlAnyElement
protected Element any;
```

I was trying to find a workaround, but everywhere it's said that xs:any is handled with no configuration. The only way to have xs:any element as java.lang.Object is to drop **xjc:simple** or change **processContents to "strict"** in xsd. None of these options are acceptable right now for me as I can't change xml schema and I have some legacy code that depends on java classes generated with xjc:simple mode but now I need to use xs:any element and I would like to avoid using org.w3c.dom.Element objects.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [Wildcard plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Wildcard+Plugin) from [JAXB2 Basics](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins). This allows you to customize lax/skip/strict wildcard binding modes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:wildcard="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/wildcard"
    jaxb:version="2.1"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="wildcard">

...

    <xs:complexType name="issueJIIB10Type" mixed="true">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <wildcard:lax/>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
            <xs:extension base="xs:anyType"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType> 

...

</xs:schema>
```

You don't have to change the schema for this, you can use this customization via binding files.

Comment: I even read about this plugin, but wasn't sure if this is the right direction. Thanks for the reply - I'll verify that as soon as I have some spare time in the project.

Comment: Thanks lexicore, this plugin is almost what I needed. I said almost because I couldn't find a way to change globally all xs:any to java.lang.Object. Every situation must be configured separately, what is a bit annoying. Just for the record for anyone that might need to configure it via binding file (plugin doc does not cover this case at all), you have to point directly to the complex type, for example:  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='elementName']/xs:complexType"><wildcard:lax/></jxb:bindings>

Comment: @Arek Please file an issue in JAXB2 Basics, this is doable.

Comment: @Arek

Done, please check the current snapshot (0.6.4-SNAPSHOT).

Docs:

http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Wildcard+Plugin

Test project:

https://svn.java.net/svn/jaxb2-commons~svn/basics/trunk/tests/wildcard/

Comment: Perfect - that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks lexicore.

Comment: thx man but this is index page to all plugin. But page with wildcard plugin is not created: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Wildcard-Plugin. Why nobody keeps this plugin/wiki page up to date ?

Comment: @hudi Because it's effort and time is a limited resource. Feel free to contribute, it's open source.

Comment: yea sure I know but when someone got effort to write plugin but he has no effort to write documentation it is kind strange

Comment: @hudi I've documented it but the old Confluence server passed away and I have no time to write new docs.

Comment: ah ok then my bad

Comment: @hudi The documentation is back.