# JAXB unmarshal part of XML into classes and leave rest as Element or Node

Tags: java, jaxb

Is there a way to unmarshal a XML document partially into Java classes (e.g. up to a certain depth), and leave the rest as Nodes or Elements (or even XML String or Document), accessible from the unmarshalled part.

E.g. I have an XML:

```
<customer>
  <name>Mike</name>
  <items>
    <item>Car</item>
    <item>Boat</item>
  </items>
</customer>
```

And Java class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    // something like this:
    private Node items;
    // or like this:
    // private String items;
}
```

The reason is because I'm not interested in the `items` part, I will never parse or access it in Java.
But I need to be able to save it and later retrieve it and generate a full XML document. The `name` element on the other hand I will use in Java code.

I want that the schema of the `items` part (at least the sub-elements) can be changed without me having to change the Java classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` to handle this use case. This annotation allows you to unmarshall any XML to a Java object (DOM Node).

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    private Object items;    
}
```

The marshaller will write the XML nodes properly

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at that feature. Do you know if I can use xjb (xjc bindings) to put that annotation into the automatically generated classes?

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293634/jaxb-2-1-customize-xsany-binding It has a link to Jaxb documentation and a extra plugin if default options are not suitable for you schema